# Изменить позицию Баннерной рекламы через .smali

Tags: android, reverse-engineering, smali

Всем привет. Сижу уже целый день и начинаю злится. Попросили поменять позицию Баннерной рекламы. Через смали код. Реклама появляется в середине экрана, надо зделать так чтоб появлялась в верху по середине. Как это зделать в смали коде? Код прикрепляю от AdPlus.smali Буду блогадарен за любую помощ.

```
.class public Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;
.super Ljava/lang/Object;
.source "AdPlus.java"


# static fields
.field private static final DELAY_FROM_REQUEST:I = 0xe754

.field private static final DELAY_FROM_RESHOW:J = 0x2bc14L

.field private static final FIRST_LOAD_DELAY:I = 0x3a95

.field private static final TAG:Ljava/lang/String; = "AdmobPlus"

.field private static final WIN_SIZE:I = -0x2


# instance fields
.field private adRequest:Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdRequest;

.field private adView:Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdView;

.field private ad_bann_id:Ljava/lang/String;

.field private ad_interstitial_id:Ljava/lang/String;

.field ctxt:Landroid/content/Context;

.field private handler:Landroid/os/Handler;

.field private interstitialAd:Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/InterstitialAd;

.field private is_closed:Z

.field private reShowBannRun:Ljava/lang/Runnable;

.field private reloadBannRun:Ljava/lang/Runnable;

.field private reloadInterstRun:Ljava/lang/Runnable;

.field private test:Z

.field private test_devices_id:[Ljava/lang/String;

.field private windowManager:Landroid/view/WindowManager;

.field private windowView:Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/FrameL;

.field private x:I

.field private y:I


# direct methods
.method public constructor <init>(Landroid/content/Context;)V
    .locals 4
    .param p1, "context"    # Landroid/content/Context;

    .prologue
    const/4 v0, 0x1

    const/4 v2, 0x0

    .line 58
    invoke-direct {p0}, Ljava/lang/Object;-><init>()V

    .line 29
    iput-boolean v2, p0, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;->test:Z

    .line 31
    iput-boolean v2, p0, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;->is_closed:Z

    .line 33
    new-array v0, v0, [Ljava/lang/String;

    .line 35
    sget-object v1, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdRequest;->DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR:Ljava/lang/String;

    aput-object v1, v0, v2

    iput-object v0, p0, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;->test_devices_id:[Ljava/lang/String;

    .line 42
    const-string v0, "ca-app-pub-8230209802532093/58535569643"

    iput-object v0, p0, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;->ad_bann_id:Ljava/lang/String;

    .line 43
    const-string v0, "ca-app-pub-8230209802532093/42372869547"

    iput-object v0, p0, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;->ad_interstitial_id:Ljava/lang/String;

    .line 123
    new-instance v0, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;

    invoke-direct {v0, p0}, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;-><init>(Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;)V

    iput-object v0, p0, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;->reloadBannRun:Ljava/lang/Runnable;

    .line 138
    new-instance v0, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;

    invoke-direct {v0, p0}, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;-><init>(Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;)V

    iput-object v0, p0, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;->reShowBannRun:Ljava/lang/Runnable;

    .line 161
    new-instance v0, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;

    invoke-direct {v0, p0}, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;-><init>(Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;)V

    iput-object v0, p0, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;->reloadInterstRun:Ljava/lang/Runnable;

    .line 177
    iput v2, p0, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;->x:I

    iput v2, p0, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;->y:I

    .line 60
    iput-object p1, p0, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;->ctxt:Landroid/content/Context;

    .line 61
    new-instance v0, Landroid/os/Handler;

    invoke-direct {v0}, Landroid/os/Handler;-><init>()V

    iput-object v0, p0, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;->handler:Landroid/os/Handler;

    .line 62
    invoke-direct {p0}, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;->initRequest()V

    .line 64
    invoke-direct {p0}, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;->initBann()V

    .line 65
    iget-object v0, p0, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;->handler:Landroid/os/Handler;

    new-instance v1, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;

    invoke-direct {v1, p0}, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;-><init>(Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;)V

    .line 71
    const-wide/16 v2, 0x3a95

    .line 65
    invoke-virtual {v0, v1, v2, v3}, Landroid/os/Handler;->postDelayed(Ljava/lang/Runnable;J)Z

    .line 73
    invoke-direct {p0}, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;->initInterstit()V

    .line 74
    invoke-direct {p0}, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;->loadInterstitial()V

    .line 75
    return-void
.end method

.method static synthetic access<#value#>(Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;)V
    .locals 0

    .prologue
    .line 108
    invoke-direct {p0}, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;->loadBanner()V

    return-void
.end method

.method static synthetic access(Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;Z)V
    .locals 0

    .prologue
    .line 31
    iput-boolean p1, p0, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;->is_closed:Z

    return-void
.end method

.method static synthetic access(Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;)Z
    .locals 1

    .prologue
    .line 31
    iget-boolean v0, p0, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;->is_closed:Z

    return v0
.end method

.method static synthetic access(Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;I)Ljava/lang/String;
    .locals 1

    .prologue
    .line 331
    invoke-direct {p0, p1}, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;->getDescriptionFromError(I)Ljava/lang/String;

    move-result-object v0

    return-object v0
.end method

.method static synthetic access(Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;)V
    .locals 0

    .prologue
    .line 117
    invoke-direct {p0}, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;->postReLoadBanner()V

    return-void
.end method

.method static synthetic access(Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;)V
    .locals 0

    .prologue
    .line 155
    invoke-direct {p0}, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;->postReLoadInterstitial()V

    return-void
.end method

.method static synthetic access(Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;)Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/InterstitialAd;
    .locals 1

    .prologue
    .line 52
    iget-object v0, p0, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;->interstitialAd:Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/InterstitialAd;

    return-object v0
.end method

.method static synthetic access(Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;)Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdView;
    .locals 1

    .prologue
    .line 50
    iget-object v0, p0, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;->adView:Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdView;

    return-object v0
.end method

.method static synthetic access(Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;)V
    .locals 0

    .prologue
    .line 148
    invoke-direct {p0}, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;->loadInterstitial()V

    return-void
.end method

.method static synthetic access(Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;I)V
    .locals 0

    .prologue
    .line 177
    iput p1, p0, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;->x:I

    return-void
.end method

.method static synthetic access(Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;I)V
    .locals 0

    .prologue
    .line 177
    iput p1, p0, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;->y:I

    return-void
.end method

.method static synthetic access(Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;)Landroid/view/WindowManager;
    .locals 1

    .prologue
    .line 48
    iget-object v0, p0, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;->windowManager:Landroid/view/WindowManager;

    return-object v0
.end method

.method static synthetic access(Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;)I
    .locals 1

    .prologue
    .line 177
    iget v0, p0, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;->x:I

    return v0
.end method

.method static synthetic access(Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;)I
    .locals 1

    .prologue
    .line 177
    iget v0, p0, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;->y:I

    return v0
.end method

.method static synthetic access(Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;)Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/FrameL;
    .locals 1

    .prologue
    .line 49
    iget-object v0, p0, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;->windowView:Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/FrameL;

    return-object v0
.end method

.method private createWindow()V
    .locals 6

    .prologue
    const/4 v1, -0x2

    .line 181
    new-instance v0, Landroid/view/WindowManager$LayoutParams;

    .line 184
    const/16 v3, 0x7d2

    .line 185
    const/16 v4, 0x28

    .line 191
    const/4 v5, -0x3

    move v2, v1

    .line 181
    invoke-direct/range {v0 .. v5}, Landroid/view/WindowManager$LayoutParams;-><init>(IIIII)V

    .line 193
    .local v0, "params":Landroid/view/WindowManager$LayoutParams;
    iget v1, p0, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;->x:I

    iput v1, v0, Landroid/view/WindowManager$LayoutParams;->x:I

    .line 194
    iget v1, p0, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;->y:I

    iput v1, v0, Landroid/view/WindowManager$LayoutParams;->y:I

    .line 196
    iget-object v1, p0, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;->windowView:Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/FrameL;

    new-instance v2, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;

    invoke-direct {v2, p0, v0}, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;-><init>(Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;Landroid/view/WindowManager$LayoutParams;)V

    invoke-virtual {v1, v2}, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/FrameL;->setOnTouchListener(Landroid/view/View$OnTouchListener;)V

    .line 230
    iget-object v1, p0, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;->windowManager:Landroid/view/WindowManager;

    iget-object v2, p0, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;->windowView:Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/FrameL;

    invoke-interface {v1, v2, v0}, Landroid/view/WindowManager;->addView(Landroid/view/View;Landroid/view/ViewGroup$LayoutParams;)V

    .line 231
    return-void
.end method

.method private destroyWindow()V
    .locals 2

    .prologue
    .line 173
    iget-object v0, p0, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;->windowView:Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/FrameL;

    const/4 v1, 0x0

    invoke-virtual {v0, v1}, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/FrameL;->setOnTouchListener(Landroid/view/View$OnTouchListener;)V

    .line 174
    iget-object v0, p0, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;->windowManager:Landroid/view/WindowManager;

    iget-object v1, p0, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;->windowView:Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/FrameL;

    invoke-interface {v0, v1}, Landroid/view/WindowManager;->removeView(Landroid/view/View;)V

    .line 175
    return-void
.end method

.method private getDescriptionFromError(I)Ljava/lang/String;
    .locals 1
    .param p1, "errorCode"    # I

    .prologue
    .line 333
    const-string v0, ""

    .line 334
    .local v0, "err_description":Ljava/lang/String;
    packed-switch p1, :pswitch_data_0

    .line 352
    :goto_0
    return-object v0

    .line 337
    :pswitch_0
    const-string v0, "internal error"

    .line 338
    goto :goto_0

    .line 341
    :pswitch_1
    const-string v0, "invalid request"

    .line 342
    goto :goto_0

    .line 345
    :pswitch_2
    const-string v0, "network error"

    .line 346
    goto :goto_0

    .line 349
    :pswitch_3
    const-string v0, "code no fill"

    goto :goto_0

    .line 334
    :pswitch_data_0
    .packed-switch 0x0
        :pswitch_0
        :pswitch_1
        :pswitch_2
        :pswitch_3
    .end packed-switch
.end method

.method private initBann()V
    .locals 2

    .prologue
    .line 236
    iget-object v0, p0, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;->ctxt:Landroid/content/Context;

    const-string v1, "window"

    invoke-virtual {v0, v1}, Landroid/content/Context;->getSystemService(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;

    move-result-object v0

    check-cast v0, Landroid/view/WindowManager;

    iput-object v0, p0, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;->windowManager:Landroid/view/WindowManager;

    .line 238
    new-instance v0, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/FrameL;

    iget-object v1, p0, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;->ctxt:Landroid/content/Context;

    invoke-direct {v0, v1}, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/FrameL;-><init>(Landroid/content/Context;)V

    iput-object v0, p0, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;->windowView:Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/FrameL;

    .line 240
    new-instance v0, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdView;

    iget-object v1, p0, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;->ctxt:Landroid/content/Context;

    invoke-direct {v0, v1}, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdView;-><init>(Landroid/content/Context;)V

    iput-object v0, p0, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;->adView:Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdView;

    .line 242
    iget-object v0, p0, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;->windowView:Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/FrameL;

    iget-object v1, p0, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;->adView:Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdView;

    invoke-virtual {v0, v1}, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/FrameL;->addView(Landroid/view/View;)V

    .line 244
    iget-object v0, p0, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;->adView:Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdView;

    sget-object v1, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdSize;->BANNER:Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdSize;

    invoke-virtual {v0, v1}, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdView;->setAdSize(Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdSize;)V

    .line 245
    iget-object v0, p0, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;->adView:Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdView;

    iget-object v1, p0, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;->ad_bann_id:Ljava/lang/String;

    invoke-virtual {v0, v1}, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdView;->setAdUnitId(Ljava/lang/String;)V

    .line 248
    iget-object v0, p0, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;->adView:Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdView;

    new-instance v1, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;

    invoke-direct {v1, p0}, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;-><init>(Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;)V

    invoke-virtual {v0, v1}, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdView;->setAdListener(Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdListener;)V

    .line 295
    return-void
.end method

.method private initInterstit()V
    .locals 2

    .prologue
    .line 300
    new-instance v0, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/InterstitialAd;

    iget-object v1, p0, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;->ctxt:Landroid/content/Context;

    invoke-direct {v0, v1}, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/InterstitialAd;-><init>(Landroid/content/Context;)V

    iput-object v0, p0, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;->interstitialAd:Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/InterstitialAd;

    .line 301
    iget-object v0, p0, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;->interstitialAd:Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/InterstitialAd;

    iget-object v1, p0, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;->ad_interstitial_id:Ljava/lang/String;

    invoke-virtual {v0, v1}, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/InterstitialAd;->setAdUnitId(Ljava/lang/String;)V

    .line 303
    iget-object v0, p0, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;->interstitialAd:Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/InterstitialAd;

    new-instance v1, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;

    invoke-direct {v1, p0}, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;-><init>(Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;)V

    invoke-virtual {v0, v1}, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/InterstitialAd;->setAdListener(Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdListener;)V

    .line 329
    return-void
.end method

.method private initRequest()V
    .locals 6

    .prologue
    .line 384
    new-instance v1, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdRequest$Builder;

    invoke-direct {v1}, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdRequest$Builder;-><init>()V

    .line 386
    .local v1, "builder":Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdRequest$Builder;
    iget-boolean v4, p0, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;->test:Z

    if-eqz v4, :cond_1

    .line 388
    iget-object v4, p0, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;->test_devices_id:[Ljava/lang/String;

    if-eqz v4, :cond_0

    .line 389
    const/4 v3, 0x0

    .local v3, "n":I
    :goto_0
    iget-object v4, p0, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;->test_devices_id:[Ljava/lang/String;

    array-length v4, v4

    if-lt v3, v4, :cond_2

    .line 393
    .end local v3    # "n":I
    :cond_0
    iget-object v4, p0, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;->ctxt:Landroid/content/Context;

    invoke-virtual {v4}, Landroid/content/Context;->getContentResolver()Landroid/content/ContentResolver;

    move-result-object v4

    const-string v5, "android_id"

    invoke-static {v4, v5}, Landroid/provider/Settings$Secure;->getString(Landroid/content/ContentResolver;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;

    move-result-object v0

    .line 396
    .local v0, "android_id":Ljava/lang/String;
    if-eqz v0, :cond_1

    .line 398
    invoke-static {v0}, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/MD5;->calculate(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;

    move-result-object v4

    invoke-virtual {v4}, Ljava/lang/String;->toUpperCase()Ljava/lang/String;

    move-result-object v2

    .line 400
    .local v2, "device_id":Ljava/lang/String;
    if-eqz v2, :cond_1

    .line 401
    invoke-virtual {v1, v2}, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdRequest$Builder;->addTestDevice(Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdRequest$Builder;

    .line 405
    .end local v0    # "android_id":Ljava/lang/String;
    .end local v2    # "device_id":Ljava/lang/String;
    :cond_1
    invoke-virtual {v1}, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdRequest$Builder;->build()Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdRequest;

    move-result-object v4

    iput-object v4, p0, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;->adRequest:Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdRequest;

    .line 406
    return-void

    .line 390
    .restart local v3    # "n":I
    :cond_2
    iget-object v4, p0, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;->test_devices_id:[Ljava/lang/String;

    aget-object v4, v4, v3

    invoke-virtual {v1, v4}, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdRequest$Builder;->addTestDevice(Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdRequest$Builder;

    .line 389
    add-int/lit8 v3, v3, 0x1

    goto :goto_0
.end method

.method private loadBanner()V
    .locals 4

    .prologue
    .line 110
    const-string v0, "AdmobPlus"

    new-instance v1, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

    const-string v2, "loadBanner()... isTestDevice = "

    invoke-direct {v1, v2}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;-><init>(Ljava/lang/String;)V

    iget-object v2, p0, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;->adRequest:Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdRequest;

    iget-object v3, p0, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;->ctxt:Landroid/content/Context;

    invoke-virtual {v2, v3}, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdRequest;->isTestDevice(Landroid/content/Context;)Z

    move-result v2

    invoke-virtual {v1, v2}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;->append(Z)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

    move-result-object v1

    invoke-virtual {v1}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;->toString()Ljava/lang/String;

    move-result-object v1

    invoke-static {v0, v1}, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/L;->d(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)I

    .line 112
    iget-object v0, p0, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;->adView:Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdView;

    const/16 v1, 0x8

    invoke-virtual {v0, v1}, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdView;->setVisibility(I)V

    .line 114
    iget-object v0, p0, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;->adView:Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdView;

    iget-object v1, p0, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;->adRequest:Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdRequest;

    invoke-virtual {v0, v1}, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdView;->loadAd(Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdRequest;)V

    .line 115
    return-void
.end method

.method private loadInterstitial()V
    .locals 2

    .prologue
    .line 150
    const-string v0, "AdmobPlus"

    const-string v1, "loadInterstitial()... "

    invoke-static {v0, v1}, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/L;->d(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)I

    .line 152
    iget-object v0, p0, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;->interstitialAd:Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/InterstitialAd;

    iget-object v1, p0, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdPlus;->adRequest:Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdRequest;

    invoke-virtual {v0, v1}, Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/InterstitialAd;->loadAd(Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdRequest;)V

    .line 153
    return-void
.end method
```

К сожалению весь код не влез. Кто в этом разберается, отпишитесь пожалуйста.

Comment: и чего же те кто вас о этом попросил, не предоставили исходный код?

Comment: Мое дело исправить ошибку. Вот прошу о помощи. Ишодного кода толи нет толи еще чтото. Знаете как зделать?

Comment: ваше дело еще так же хотя бы немного задумываться над тем что вас просят сделать, а тут налицо какие то темные делишки, так как у разработчика всегда есть исходники, но даже если представим что он их потерял, то он сам попытается что либо подкрутить в smali, хотя и занятие тупиковое имхо.